# Ms Access VBA delete query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to delete the currently displayed record in access vba form

```
db.Execute ("Delete From [Score] Where ([AdmNo] LIKE Forms!FormFirst!students AND [Term] LIKE Forms!FormFirst!Term)")
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please explain your issue a bit better.  I can tell that you may have issues with combining that string that way. How about this?  `db.Execute ("Delete From [Score] Where ([AdmNo] LIKE '" & Forms!FormFirst!students & "' AND [Term] LIKE '" & Forms!FormFirst!Term & "')")`

Comment: LIKE without wildcard might as well just be = sign. Those inner parens are not needed. Concatenate variables.

Comment: Delete the current record of the form. Simple and no SQL.

Answer (score 0):

So thank you all for your response, after thorough study and trial, i figured out that i need to convert the form value to a text and since the field i was doing the comparison on was declared as text so this work for me

SQL = "DELETE FROM [Score] WHERE [AdmNo] = '" & Me!students & "' AND [Term] = '" & Me!Term & "'"

so if the AdmNo and Term was declared as number, then this will now be the case
SQL = "DELETE FROM [Score] WHERE [AdmNo] = " & Me!students & " AND [Term] = " & Me!Term & "" and just the removal of single quote and the inclusion did the trick. data type wahala

Answer (score 0):

- try this:

  currentdb.Execute ("Delete From [Score] Where ([AdmNo] LIKE '

> *" & Forms!FormFirst!students & "
>   *' AND [Term] LIKE '
>   *" & Forms!FormFirst!Term & "'
>   *)")